# Does $ra returns the address of current instruction or the next instruction?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I am very confused in the concept of returning address by $ra. Does it return the address of the **current instruction** being executed or the **instruction to be executed next**? For explanation please use the following code,

> 1. Consider a code fragment that calls three functions func_A,
>      func_B, and func_C. The Instruction 1 is located at address 1996. What
>      would be loaded in register $ra when each of the three functions is
>      called?

```
Instruction 1
Instruction 2
jal func_A
Instruction 3
jal func_B
Instruction 4
jal func_C
Instruction 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't remember the mips arch but it's logical that the return address is the instruction to be executed next, otherwise you would be in an infinite loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The next instruction is stored in $ra

So, when calling func_A, $ra = 2008; when calling func_B, $ra = 2016; when calling func_C, $ra = 2024.

This is logical, because you return from a subroutine by `jr $ra`, thus jumping to the instruction after the subroutine call.

Comment: You forgot about the MIPS branch delay slot after each JAL.  Instruction 3 is executed before the start of func_A, so $ra will contain the address of "jal func_B" i.e.2012 at the start of func_A. Similarly $ra contains 2020 when calling $func_B, and 2028 when calling func_C.